# Calling Drupal service for POST

Tags: java, drupal-8, spring-webflux

I am using Drupal for cms in my java code and I am getting following issue when I tries to post some data.

```
  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: Internal Server Error in Drupal\rest\Plugin\rest\resource\EntityResource->post() (line 198 of /var/www/html/drupal8/drupal/core/modules/rest/src/Plugin/rest/resource/EntityResource.php).
```

and I observed one more strange thing.

My Request Payload is.

```
                      "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "op1",
                        "value": "Narendera Modi"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "op2",
                        "value": "Rahul Gandhi"
                    }
                ],
```

and my code which is posting into drupla is

```
     return Flux.fromIterable(options).flatMap(option -> {
            DrupalRequestModel drupalRequestModel = new DrupalRequestModel();

            List<CustomMapObject> type = new ArrayList<>();
            CustomMapObject typeMap = new CustomMapObject();
            typeMap.put("target_id", "answer");
            type.add(typeMap);

            drupalRequestModel.setType(type);

            List<CustomMapObject> title = new ArrayList<>();
            CustomMapObject titleMap = new CustomMapObject();
            titleMap.put("value", "question banl");
            title.add(titleMap);

            drupalRequestModel.setTitle(title);

            List<CustomMapObject> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();
            CustomMapObject fieldMap = new CustomMapObject();
            fieldMap.put("value", option.getValue());
            fieldList.add(fieldMap);

            drupalRequestModel.setField_value(fieldList);

            return webClient.post()
                    .bodyValue(drupalRequestModel)
                    .exchange().flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(ContentCMSResponse.class))
                    .map(response -> {
                        DrupalResponse drupalResponse = new DrupalResponse();
                        Options op = new Options();
                        op.setId(option.getId());
                        op.setCmsId(response.getUuid().get(0).get("value"));
                        options.add(op);
                        drupalResponse.setOptions(options);
                        return drupalResponse;
                    });
        });
```

As you can see I am iterating over this and creating a request model for drupal and hit the post call.
I am getting only this error if I have more than one object in array for single object code is working fine.

Does someone face this kind of issue before?

Comment: i cant answer your question but you have several strange things that tell me you have no idea what you are doing. Why this `BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(drupalRequestModel)` when you can do `.bodyValue(drupalRequestModel)` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body

Comment: and what is the purpose of this `.flatMapMany(Flux::just)`

Comment: actually i was just using trial and error approach because i am trying to find why drupal is throwing this particular errror that's why you will see some strange code there. I would appreciate if you ignore my coding practices here and help me with the issue i am facing

Comment: i just said to ignore those practices of using .fromPublisher instead of .bodyValue anyway i have removed those two things which you pointed out still I am getting the same issue.
It is an intermittent issue sometimes it runs successfully and sometimes this error occurs.

Comment: well since you have an internal error on line 198 in your php code, why don't you start by looking there?

Comment: that's the thing I don't have the php code in my system... the drupal is running on my   companies server and right now I cannot access it. This is my first time working with drupal and the code itself is not a bit complicated. I am just not able to figure out what  is going wrong here. I know asynchronous programming is doing something wrong here I just don't know what. why drupal is throwing error in this case. just getting this response from drupal "the-website-encountered-an-unexpected-error-please-try"

Comment: first of all Webflux is not per say always async. flatMap is an async operation yes but Mono and Flux are thread agnostic, and not necessarily async. You are taking a list with two items, putting them in a flux, when the two items are concidered "completed" (that is right away) they are emitted. flatMap is an async operation so two threads will start running the code in the flatmap making two requests to your drupal server. Is it a race condition? do the operations need to be done after each other?

Comment: yes I do not wants my request's to overlap if they do then there might be a race condition here. is there a way to remove that possibility even if I am using Flux here.

Comment: Flux has a function called `flatMapSequencial` if i remember correctly that will enforce order